# Can Android's source code be mapped to its software stack?

Tags: android, git

The Android's software stack diagram is the first thing you see when you learn Android. However, in the actual Android Git repo, nothing is said about each directory's relation with the diagram.

My question is, is it possible to associate each source code directory to the diagram's defined functionalities? It would be a lot easier to read through Android's source code knowing what each directory does, on a high level, instead of guessing each directory's use purely by its name (ex. ActivityManager.java must mean it runs activity manager). Has someone already done this, or it's simply not associable?

Git repo is here: https://android.googlesource.com/

Android software stack is here:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, partially there are some mappings could be found between the diagram above and android source code, like `dalvik` with Davik Virtual Machine.

The rest you'll find hard to map. The diagram above is built in business relation between components. Take `Libraries` components for example, there will be internal libs for Android project, and external libs from 3rd party, which could be found in both `libs` and `extlibs` directory.

Reference: http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/development/pdk/docs/intro_source_code.html#androidSourceCodeDirectoriesDevice